# What's the difference between a makor and a shoresh in the Alter Rebbe’s Tanya?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, tanya, baal-hatanya

What's the difference between a makor and a shoresh in the Alter Rebbe’s Tanya? My melamed told me in yeshiva but I forgot. I think one is from a higher source. I think it's in the Rebbe's notes but I don't have this sefer.

Comment: Can you please show examples in which major and Shoresh are used in Tanya?